# Get Application context with Dagger2

Tags: android, kotlin, dagger-2, mvp

I make an application using the MVP pattern and I would need to have the context of the application to access the getString() method.
For this, I use Dagger2 except that I don't know how to implement it

So here's what I've been doing so far:

**BaseApplication.kt**

```
class BaseApplication: Application() {

    lateinit var component: ApplicationComponent

    override fun onCreate() {
        super.onCreate()
        instance = this
        component = buildComponent()
        component.inject(this)
    }

    fun buildComponent(): ApplicationComponent {
        return DaggerApplicationComponent.builder()
            .applicationModule(ApplicationModule(this))
            .build()
    }

    fun getApplicationComponent(): ApplicationComponent {
        return component
    }

    companion object {
        lateinit var instance: BaseApplication private set
    }
}
```

**ApplicationComponent.kt**

```
@Component(modules = arrayOf(ApplicationModule::class))
interface ApplicationComponent {

    fun inject(application: Application)

}
```

**ApplicationModule.kt**

```
@Module
class ApplicationModule(private val context: Context) {


    @Singleton
    @Provides
    @NonNull
    fun provideContext(): Context {
        return context
    }
}
```

I want to provide the context of BaseApplication into the adapter of my recyclerview because I need to have access to the getString method.

What do I have to do now that I've done this to get the context in my adapter ?

Comment: what do you need the context for ? Btw, you get it in the `onCreateViewHolder` method

Comment: Unrelated to Dagger, but you should use `parent.getContext()` or `viewHolder.view.getContext()` instead so that you have the correct themes & configurations applied

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To provide the `applicationContext` in dagger, create a new scope.

```
@javax.inject.Qualifier
annotation class ForApplication
```

Then in your `ApplicationModule`, you provide this dependency using the scope.

```
@Singleton
@Provides
@NonNull
@ForApplication
fun provideContext(): Context {
    return context
}
```

Now anywhere you want to use this context, just prefix it with this scope. For example

```
@Inject
class YourAdapter extends Adapter {
    YourAdapter(@ForApplication Context context) {

    }
}
```